# Analytically controlling sizes in modular arithmetic to demonstrate Dirichlet pigeonhole application

Tags: nt.number-theory, algorithms, diophantine-equations, closed-form-expressions, diophantine-geometry

Given $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb Z$ with $ad+bc=p$ a prime there is an $m\in\mathbb Z$ with $-\lceil1+\sqrt{p}\rceil<
r_1,r_2<\lceil1+\sqrt{p}\rceil$ and
$$r_1\equiv mac\bmod p$$
$$r_2\equiv mbd\bmod p$$
where $r_1,r_2$ are interpreted as in $[-\frac p2,\frac p2]$ by Dirichlet's pigeonhole principle.

1. Is there any closed form for such an $m$ and hence $r_1$ and $r_2$ as well?
2. Can we canonize an expression that provides an unique $m$ that works for a given $a,b,c,d$ at least under unimodular condition of $ad-bc=1$ (there may be multiple $m$'s however I am asking if we can isolate an expression that works always providing an unique $m$)?
3. Say if 1. and 2. fails then at least is there a $\mathsf{polylog}(|a|+|b|+|c|+|d|)$ time algorithm to find such an $m$ that does not involve linear integer programming (with linear integer programming there is Lenstra's method which is not very practical)?

Comment: Doesn't e.g. $|r_1|\lt\lceil1+\sqrt{p}\rceil$ immediately subsume $r_1\in [-p/2, p/2]$?

Comment: The range is to stress that the modulus is not defined from $0$ to $p-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 3. one might use the $LLL$ algorithm to find the shortest vector to the row space of the equations $$\begin{bmatrix}bd&-ac&-p\\1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}r_1\\r_2\\k\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\r_1\\r_2\end{bmatrix}.$$